# Proof of a property of fuzzy extension principle

Tags: fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

I'm looking for a proof of the following property of the fuzzy extension principle:

$$
B \supseteq f(f^{-1}(B))
$$

($f: X\rightarrow Y$ is an arbitrary crisp function, and $B$ is a fuzzy set). I think if f is a function, the two sides would be equal. But I see this property on page 47 of the book by Klir and Yuan.

Thank you.

Comment: Even if $f$ is a function and $B$ a set, the two sides are equal only if $B$ is contained in the image of $f$.  So we should not expect more than the inclusion of (fuzzy) sets shown.

Answer (score 1):

$f\left(f^{-1}\left(B\right)\right)\subseteq B$ is always true, which
is not the case for $B\subseteq f\left(f^{-1}\left(B\right)\right)$
(see the answer of 5xgum). It is true for each $B$ if and only if
$f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

"I think if $f$ is a function, the two sides would be equal"

Not really, look at the function $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$ and $B=[-1,0)$. Since $f^{-1}(B)=\emptyset$, it follows that $f(f^{-1}(B))=\emptyset$.

Comment: so, can I conclude that $f(f^{-1}(B))$ is either empty or equal to $B$?

Comment: You can only conclude something if you can prove it. Can you prove what you just wrote? (hint: can you find such a $B$ for the function $x^2$ that $f(f^{-1}(B))$ is neither empty nor equal to $B$?

Comment: well, I guess $B=[-1,1]$ would do. but how can we prove the property?

Answer (score -1):

As you said, $f$ is a crisp function, so it will only work with those elements that ARE or ARE NOT in $X$, and the same for $Y$.

Note that $B:Y\to [0,1]$ and $f^{-1}$ will take those $y$ in $Y$ such that $B(y)=1$ (you can call that subset of $Y$, $B^{-1}(\{1\})$) and relate them with some $x$ in $X$ such that $f(x)=y$, if it does exist.

Now, the subset of $X$ made of those $x$'s will be returned to $Y$ with $f$, into a subset of $B^{-1}(\{1\})$, because if some $y$ in $B^{-1}(\{1\})$ actually doesn't have a preimage.

So, $f(f^{-1}(B)) \subset B^{-1}(\{1\}) \subset B$, because in fact it may have existed a $y_0$ in $Y$ such that $B(y_0)=\frac{1}{2}$, for say something, and it wouldn't even be in $B^{-1}(\{1\})$.

(Sorry for the mecca font; hope this helps you 1 year after you published it)